# Eclipse remote debug failure

Tags: eclipse, qt, arm, remote-debugging

I've prepared Eclipse to compile Qt programs for mini2440 friendly-arm board. I compiled a sample program successfully. But when I want to debug it remotely I get this error:

> Error during file upload. Failed to connect sshd on "192.168.1.230:22"

My connection is connected successfully and I can ping 192.168.1.230 but I can't run and debug a program remotely with it.
Would somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have sshd running on your target. Google an ssh server for your arm board and install it.